# Как сделать функционал без условных операторов? JS

Tags: javascript

Создается переменная,в которую будет помещен ответ пользователя через prompt.
Если пользователь ввел число,то следующим сообщением вывести число,которое он написал(через alert), если строку, то написать,что допущена ошибка.

Код должен быть написан строго без использования Операторов условий.

В голову ничего не приходит дельного. Пытался что-то писать через операторы сравнений,но не получается создать последовательность после проверки на тип данных

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем без условных операторов или инструкций, можно так:

```js
function check(input) {
  const functions = new Map();
  functions.set(NaN, () => { alert('Error!'); });

  function number() { alert(input); }

  input = Number(input);

  (functions.get(input) ?? number)();
}

check('1')
check('-1.5')
check('1foo')
check('bar')
```